# How can I excute Notepad by Java code

Tags: java

I want to open Notepad program in MS Windows by Java code to open my text file.

Pls help me to do that.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `java.awt.Desktop` if using Java 1.6, `.txt` is registered to the notepad and Desktop is supported:

```
    if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        System.err.println("Desktop not supported");
        // use alternative (Runtime.exec)
        return;
    }

    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    if (!desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.EDIT)) {
        System.err.println("EDIT not supported");
        // use alternative (Runtime.exec)
        return;
    }

    try {
        desktop.edit(new File("test.txt"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this way you can open/edit files in a more OS independent way.

Answer (score 3):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad c:/asd.txt");
```

where `c:/asd.txt` is the full path to your text file. If `/` doesn't work for you, use `\\` instead.

Answer (score 3):

use the ProcessBuilder Class

```
 Process p = new ProcessBuilder("notepad", "file.txt").start();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have registered the .txt extension on your OS and your text file already exists then you can do even

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","text.txt"});
```

The advantage is it will take the program associated with .txt, what could be diferent from notepad.exe.

Comment: Using `java.awt.Desktop.open` is probably a much better way of doing that.