# Java code to run applications

Tags: java, runtime

I need a java code to allow me to run this notepad and open a specified file, for example :

```
String []a={"C:/Users/day/Desktop/a.txt"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad",a);
```

This code runs notepad but does not open the file `a.txt`.
What can be the problem ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487149/how-to-open-the-notepad-file-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument in [`exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) represents the environmental variables. You want

```
String[] a = { "notepad", "C:/Users/day/Desktop/a.txt" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need double slashes in your file name, and all of your command args can be in the same array.

```
String[] args = {"notepad.exe", "C://Users//day//Desktop//a.txt"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```